# Sublime3 - `PyV8` manual installation not working

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

In my installed sublime text, since I use the proxy, I installed the `PyV8` manually:

step1: I opened this path:

```
C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages
```

step2: and created a folder called : `PyV8` and

step3: I downloaded a zip file from : https://github.com/emmetio/pyv8-binaries and again created a new folder instead of step 2 as `pyv8-win64-p3`

step4: I unzipped the folder that I downloaded from step3 to newly created folder as `pyv8-win64-p3` (step3).

Now I restarted my sublime3, but still I am getting an error saying:

[image: Error throws like this]

any one correct what I did wrong?

Comment: Try to install into `...\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages`. You can also check out this instruction: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/478

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, close Sublime. Then, find the folder that contains `PyV8.py` and `_PyV8.pyd`. Move the contents to `C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\PyV8\win64-p3`, and delete the original `PyV8` folder in `Packages`. Restart Sublime and you should be all set.

Comment: By the way, you should disable pyv8 update, so won't get the connection error any more: set the Emmet config `"disable_pyv8_update": true`.